# SOQL count() aggregation with group by

Tags: soql

In the object `Asset` we have a custom lookup field called `License__C` and in `License__C` there's a custom lookup field called `Account__C`

i want to receive the amount of assets, per license, per account.
Something like that:
[image]

the number of assets is determined in the field `Quantity`.

i have no idea how to do this, i tried this first but i know its not even near the answer:

```
select License__r.Account__c, sum(Quantity) 
from Asset 
group by License__r.Account__c
LIMIT 50
```

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select Id, License__c,License__r.Account__c acc, sum(Quantity)  from Asset 
 GROUP BY ROLLUP (Id ,License__c,License__r.Account__c)`
Please try this one and let me know.You should always use alias for related fields.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to group by account and license, and after that count the id of assets

Try this query:

```
select License__c,License__r.Account__c, sum(Quantity)  
from Asset 
group by License__r.Account__c,License__c
LIMIT 50
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the response! however, i edited the question, i need to sum of quantity. i tried your query and changed the count(id) but haven't received anything

Comment: deleted i was wrong in my comment